# Excute PayPal Payment using REST api

Tags: rest, paypal, payment

Okay, so I've been playing around with PayPal's REST API in sandbox mode to make payments on my website. I'm not using their SDK, and I've had tons of issues with that composer thing working and their sdk doesn't seem to work with out running it.  and so far it's been less annoying figuring out to make the requests manually then to try to fix the issues getting the sdk to work.

I got through all three steps on the "Accept a PayPal Payment" and got this in the response
(after using a JSON decoder)

> ```
> [id] => PAY-5VS02203M8518634FKHMEGAI
> [create_time] => 2013-07-06T16:17:05Z
> [update_time] => 2013-07-06T16:17:31Z
> [state] => approved
> [intent] => sale
> ```

so I think I got it working,   but my big question here is does "approved" mean then that the person does in-fact have enough money to pay and I will get the money for certain.
or just that they have everything needed to attempt to charge the user but there's still a chance it may fail due to the user having NSF? the documentation on the website doesn't really say one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Until you get a transaction ID returned the transaction has not completed. You complete the payment by passing to PayPal the `id` you received above in the endpoint and the `payer_id` in the request.

I grabbed this URL straight from the sample on Developer.PayPal.com:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-34629814WL663112AKEE3AWQ/execute/
```

This may help you:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment